# A simple probability question about two types of cards

Tags: probability

There is a hidden box that contains two different types of cards--1 Card A and 1 Card B. Card A has both sides of the card red while Card B has one side red and the other blue. If you randomly picked a card and saw a red face, what is the probability that this card is of type A. Using the conditional probability equation, I seem to be getting $0.5$ as the answer, however, the true answer is $2/3$. And I dont see how you can get $2/3$?

Comment: You don't ever mention what proportion are of type A and what are type B.

Comment: @Aapeli There is only one type A and one type B in the box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand there are as many A cards as B cards in the box.

By conditional probability: $$\begin{align}\quad\Pr(A \mid\text{red}) & = \dfrac{\Pr(A \cap \text{red})}{ \Pr(\text{red})} \\ ~ & = \dfrac{\Pr(A)\Pr(\text{red}\mid A)}{\Pr(A)\Pr(\text{red}\mid A)+\Pr(B)\Pr(\text{red}\mid B)} \\ ~ & = \dfrac{{^1\!/\!_2}\cdot 1}{{^1\!/\!_2}\cdot 1+{^1\!/\!_2}\cdot{^1\!/\!_2}} \\ ~ & = \dfrac{{^1\!/\!_2}}{{^3\!/\!_4}} \\ ~ & = {^2\!/\!_3}\end{align}$$

cheers

Comment: Isn't the probability that it is of one face red and the other also red (0.5)^2

Comment: @John  Pr(get a red face) = Pr(card A) or Pr(card B and its red side) = 1/2 + 1/2.1/2 =3/4

Comment: I am referring to the Pr(AandRed). If you get a red face, it has a 0.5 chance and if it is also red on the other side then it is (0.5)^2

Comment: Pr(A and red) =Pr (to get simultaneously A and red)= Pr(to get a red card A) =Pr(to get a card A) (because A both faces are red), =1/2

Comment: I assumed that the two events were independent. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If we assume there are the same number of type 'A' cards as type 'B' cards then if you pull a card at random and look at one side only there are 4 equally likely results

Red or Red from card A.
Red or Blue from card B.

By observing a red face we can eliminate one of these options so we now have only 3 equally likely results and of these how many are using Card A?

Answer 2 of the 3 equally likely outcomes use card A so probability is $\dfrac{2}{3}$.